# Nodejs use a project in another project

Tags: node.js, git

I have a beginner question concerning nodejs. 
I'm  working on two different nodejs projects, let's say project A and project B.
And I would like to use the functionalities of project A in B.

How can I do it??

I was thinking about using git submodules. But is there a possibility to use project A as a node_module. that means that the users only have to update it if a new version of it is available?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No need to use git submodules - you can use `npm` to install a module directly from a git remote url, or directly from GitHub.

e.g.:

```
npm install <git remote url>
npm install githubname/reponame
```

See the [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for details.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this will always install the most recent version from the repo - semver isn't respected. If you add a `#` and then a  commit hash to the end, it'll lock the dependency to always use that commit.